# How to add spinner on index view to fetch in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, spinner

This is view of my collection:

```
Network.Views.Offers.Index = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection = new Network.Collections.Offers();
    this.collection
    .on('reset', this.render)
    .fetch();
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(model) {
      var view = new Network.Views.Offers.Offer({ model: model });
      $(self.el).append(view.el);
      view.adjustHeight();
    });
    return this;
  },
});
```

I tried to add and remove spinner class after successfull fetch:

```
this.$el.append('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>');
this.collection
.on('reset', this.render)
.fetch({
  success:function() {
    this.$el.removeClass('loading');
  }
});
```

But I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined
```

Comment: maybe add `wait:true` while your collection fetches data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.$el.append('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>');
```

Adds a div with a class of loading inside your $el element.

```
this.$el.removeClass('loading');
```

removeClass doesn't remove elements within an element with the specified class.

Try:

```
this.$el.append('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>');
var $this = this; // maintain the context of this within the success callback
this.collection
.on('reset', this.render)
.fetch({
  success:function() {
    $this.$('.loading').remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the TypeError because `$el` is not defined on `this` within the `success` callback. This is because `this` within the `success` callback is not referring to your `Index` View.

You need to bind `this` to that callback to make `this` refer to the `Index` View within that callback..

```
success:function() {
  this.$el.removeClass('loading');
}.bind(this)
```

Read about [`bind` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)